# Search data from specific DOM part

Tags: javascript, search

I have a search input field, and I want to get the user's input dynamically and update a list contained in a `<div>`

I'm setting up a search solution for a catalogue where you can display a list of items.

Right now all the items are shown at once.

the html

```
                <input type="search" id="search-field" placeholder="Search...">
            </div>
<div class="container">
            <p id="guide">Select a category from the menu</p>
            <ul id="product-list">
            </ul>
            <script src="./preload.js"></script>
        </div>
```

the js code

```
    var fileList = document.getElementById('product-list');

    var title = document.getElementById('guide');
    title.innerHTML = `You are looking at the ${products} catalog.`;

    for(var i = 0; i < thumbFiles.length; i++){
        var pathName = thumbFiles[i];
        var finalName = pathName.split('/').pop();
            fileList.innerHTML = document.getElementById('product-list').innerHTML + 
            `<li class="product-container">
                <div class="new-thumb">
                <a href="${(items[i])}" id='product-placeholder' target="_blank">
                    <img src="${(thumbFiles[i])}" alt="thumb" class="thumbnail">
                </a>
                <h4>${(path.parse(finalName).name)}</h4>
            </li>`
    };
}
```

I expect to update the `<ul>` with the search input text matching element from the catalogue.

Comment: *"I want to get the user's input dynamically"*: your code is never looking at the `input` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an `oninput` listener to your element, like this :

*In your js script*

```
const myInput = document.querySelector(‘#search-field’);
const fileList = document.querySelector('#product-list');

myInput.addEventListener(‘input’, () => {
  // Don’t forget to clean your results on each new input
  fileList.innerHTML = ‘’;

  for(const index in thumbFiles) {
    const pathName = thumbFiles[index];
    const finalName = pathName.split('/').pop();

    // Here is the function that will check if your current item match user input
    if (match(finalName, myInput.value)) {
      fileList.innerHTML += [your stuff]
    }
  }
});
```

this will trigger a function each time your input is changing value. Here, it calls our arrow function in which we pack all the actions we want to execute when user input some text.

**EDIT**

Forgot to compare with current input. You can get input value by calling `myInput.value`

An example of what `match()` can be :

```
function match(name, userInput) {
  return name.includes(userInput);
}
```

This will just check if the finalName contains the user input.